# Join values of two different KStreams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

So I have two different `KStream`s  like so:

Stream 1: (`String` key, `Object` value1)

Stream 2: (`String` key, `Object` value2)

I'd like to join them so that I end up with a stream that looks like (`Object` value1, `Object` value2).

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: There are a couple of join types, depending on what you want to achieve. This is in informative article that might help you further : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Join+Semantics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that works is to join the two streams such that the value of the resulting stream is a container class that contains both original values. Then, map the stream to take the values back out of the container and use one of them as the key.

Code:

```java
KStream<String, Object> stream1;
KStream<String, Object> stream2;

KStream<Object, Object> joinedStream = stream1
        .join(stream2, (value1, value2) -> new MyValueContainer(value1, value2))
        .map((key, container) -> new KeyValue<Object, Object>(container.getValue1(), container.getValue2()));
```

Comment: in the join I think you meant to write new MyValueContainer(value1, value2).

Comment: @MichalBorowiecki I did mean to do that - thanks for pointing it out